# Is pressure at all points same in a non-accelerating fluid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, pressure, acceleration

That's basically the question. If the container of a fluid is not accelerating, then can we say that pressure at all points inside the fluid is same?

Comment: A general relativist would say yes, but Newton would have said no.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: If you are stationary in the Earth's gravity of 9.81 m/s² GR treats this as the same as accelerating at 9.81 m/s². In both cases you get a pressure gradient in your fluid. Conversely if you are falling freely in Earth's gravity GR treats this as the same as floating in outer space where there is no gravity. In both cases there would be no pressure gradient in your fluid. So a general relativist would answer your question *Is pressure at all points same in a non-accelerating fluid?* by saying *Yes*, but this does rely on a specific meaning of *non-accelerating*.

Comment: More precisely, there is no pressure gradient in your fluid if and only if the [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration) is zero. Maybe I should add this as an answer ...

Comment: @JohnRennie You should add this as an answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie's was a very elegant answer, but you can really appreciate only if you are familiar with many more fields of physics than the OP currently is

Answer (score 4):

No. Pressure in a fluid depends on depth. Pressure at the bottom of a swimming pool is higher than at the surface. Atmospheric pressure is higher at sea level than at the top of a mountain.